# How to prevent an exe file from running if it is not installed with a setup file?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, exe

How to prevent an executable from executing, if it is not installed using a proper setup file? (i.e) if it is just copied from another system? I created the executable and its corresponding setup, so what should I do from my end to prevent my software getting copied from one system to another simply?

Comment: When it happens inadvertently, it's usually a result of depending on a dll or configuration file in some other directory or a registry setting or something like that... but why be difficult if there isn't *already* a *functional* reason why this is not possible?   It's hardly going to be effective for copy protection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You could test if a certain registry key exists.
- You can test the OS Version. (Client yes, Server no)
- You generate a Hardware specific id and compare this online with a database before (first / every) run.